# connection problems with Mongodb Sharding

Tags: mongodb

I have a problem, when creating a database with Mongo Sharding (Test) it works correctly while the mongod is running, but if I close the cmd where the mongod services are running, then I cannot open the database, I get this message:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hozFW.png)

I run mongod but it still doesn't work. I do it in these ways:

`...MongoDB\Server\4.4\bin> mongod`
or
`...MongoDB\Server\4.4\bin>mongod --port 20006`

Note: it also doesn't work if I run mongodb service in task manager.

Answer (score 0):

You should create the services like this:

```
mongod.exe --config ...\MongoDB\config\mongo_shard1.cfg --install
mongod.exe --config ...\MongoDB\config\mongo_config1.cfg --install
mongod.exe --config ...\MongoDB\config\mongos1.cfg --install
```

Then you should be able to start the services with Service Manager.
For a Sharded cluster you need at least 3 MongoDB services running.

Did you follow this [Deploy a Sharded Cluster](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/deploy-shard-cluster/) Tutorial?

Comment: No, I used this https://www.adictosaltrabajo.com/2016/11/29/sharding-en-mongodb/

Comment: This guideline refers to MongoDB version 3.2, which is outdated. Some commands in there are not supported anymore. Apart from that it is for Linux but you work in Windows. Follow the tutorial which matches your version 4.4